# package com.google.protobuf does not exist on OS X Maverick

Tags: protocol-buffers, osx-mavericks

I am on OS X Mavericks and starting learning about protobuf, i download the example from https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list

I am successfully able to create the .java file from the proto but while compiling the existing java code using

make java, i am getting following error

```
com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:91: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
      com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
                         ^
com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:12: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
      extends com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder {
                                 ^
com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:9: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
                         ^
com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:2495: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
  private static com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor
                                                ^
com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java:2498: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage does not exist
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.FieldAccessorTable
....
....
```

Any resolution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Met the same problem and finally got it working. Here's what I did(using version 2.6.0) on OSX 10.9:

1. Do everything `java/README.txt` tells you to
2. if `maven package` succeed, you'll get a `protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar` under `target` folder, for me it's `/Users/laike9m/Dev/protobuf-2.6.0/java/target/protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar`.
3. create `~/Library/Java/Extensions` folder, note: this is platform specific operation, for OS other than OSX it should be `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext`
4. copy `protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar` to `~/Library/Java/Extensions`

Then you should be able to run `make java` successfully.

Comment: If it's maven application, add it to dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `libprotobuf.jar` in your `CLASSPATH`.  Follow the instructions under [`java/README.txt`](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/README.txt) in the Protobuf source package to build it.

Answer (score 0):

What @laike9m suggested only partially worked for me.  I definitely tried to do everything `java/README.txt` as @laike9m suggested.  I had to install maven.  I used `brew` to do that (`brew install maven`).  I then built the protocol buffers java source using `mvn package`.  The first time I tried that, it failed due to some obscure-ish error.  I built the C++ code using `./configure && make`.  Next time I tried to build the java code using `mvn package` it worked.  It put the resulting jar in a folder called `target`.  I think went back to the examples area and was able to build the java example using `make` but I had to modify the `Makefile` by adding the `-classpath...` part below:

```
javac_middleman: AddPerson.java ListPeople.java protoc_middleman
    javac -classpath .:../java/target/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:$$CLASSPATH AddPerson.java ListPeople.java com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java
    @touch javac_middleman
```

Answer (score 0):

Download protobuf.jar from below link and add jar file into libs folder.Its work for me.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/downloads